# Why must arrays have each element of the same size?

Tags: c

It would certainly be convenient in specific contexts to have arrays of the form

|1 word| 2 words| 2 words| 2 words| 2 words|1 word| 1 word| ....

Consider for example when you want to have pointers into a linked list, with a begin/end but, when begin is the null pointer you don't need the end pointer.

Is it possible for a programming language [like C/C++] or computer to support such a concept?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: I don't understand it also. But for the first part of the question, consider using structures.

Comment: Language doesn't support multi-size arrays. You can save data contents indirectly to store multiple size arrays. For example array of head pointers of linked list or array of container etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what is not to understand. Presently in C we have arrays:

T* each element of the array have sizeof(T)

how about, {T,S}* where some elements have sizeof(T) and some have sizeof(S). In order for this concept to make sense obviously we need some rules for knowing when we are looking at an S object or a T object. This is perfectly reasonable in theory. i'm just curious why no one has done something like this.

Comment: No, it is not enough to know whether you're looking at an S object or a T object. You need to know the sizes of all preceeding elemets to calculate the address that corresponds to an index. Or you just reserve the maximum of T and S for every entry - but you can have that with unions.

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's true.. ok, this was sort of a dumb question now that I put it out there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for arrays in C or C++ to do that, because the memory address of an array element is calculated from only the address of the array, the offset, and the size of the elements.  If elements had variable size, then you'd need to scan through the array and check each element in order to find the object at any given address.

That said, I don't see any reason why you couldn't define an array-like object that behaved like you want.  It would just have O(n) indexing rather than O(1).

Comment: Or, use "array of pointer to variable sized entry". This would still have O(1) indexing (with larger values of 1).

Comment: @Brendan yes, but it will use more memory (8 bytes for pointer, and lets say another 4 for the data len = that is 12 more bytes per "node"). You are also using indirect access for each array index, which will reduce the speed of your app.

Comment: I mean, I understand what you are saying. I understand how arrays presently work. I'm asking what is the real limitation to making something different happen.

Answer (score 1):

There are many languages that have arrays in which elements are not the same size. Obviously, C/C++ is not one of those languages.

As long as you are using the language of pointers and words, you are thinking in terms of a low level language. In such a language (and there are many of them) array elements are laid out contiguously in memory and indexing into the array uses simple arithmetic. With such a scheme each array element occupies a fixed size slot. The size of each element could vary (say by using a union or a variant record type) but the size of the slot could not.

If you abandon those concepts and think in terms of higher level languages, array elements of different sizes are quite normal. Languages like Java, C#, JavaScript, Ruby, Python and Perl all provide arrays of strings, arrays of arrays, and arrays of other types which vary in size. They do this by keeping the memory used for storing values separate from the memory used for indexing.